# Accessing z-coordinate in world space in shader modifier SceneKit

Tags: ios, glsl, scenekit

### Looking for

I’m having trouble accessing the z-coordinate of the rendered pixel in world space. In SceneKit, I am looking for a 3d plane whose rendered color is directly related to the z-coordinates of the rendered point.

### Situation

I’m working with SpriteKit and I’m using a SK3DNode to embed a SceneKit scene inside my SpriteKit scene. For the SceneKit scene, I’m using a .dae Collada file exported from Blender. It contains a plane mesh and a light.
I’m applying shader modifiers to modify the geometry and the lighting model.

```
  self.waterGeometry.shaderModifiers = @{
    SCNShaderModifierEntryPointGeometry : self.geomModifier,
    SCNShaderModifierEntryPointSurface : self.cellShadingModifier
  };
```

The geometry modifier code (`self.geomModifier`):

```
// Waves Modifier
float Amplitude = 0.02;
float Frequency = 15.0;
vec2 nrm = _geometry.position.xz;
float len = length(nrm)+0.0001; // for robustness
nrm /= len;
float a = len + Amplitude*sin(Frequency * _geometry.position.z + u_time * 1.6);
_geometry.position.xz = nrm * a;
```

The geometry modifier applies a sine transformation to the `_surface` property to simulate waves. In the image below, the sketched sprites are SpriteKit sprites which have a higher zPosition and do not interfere with the SK3DNode. Notice the subtle waves (z displacement) as a result of the geometry modifier.

[image: The 3D plane, deformed using the geometry shader modifier]

The next step, I want to output color to be computed based on the point’s z-coordinate in world space. This could be either _surface.diffuse or _output.color, that doesn't matter that much to (would imply a different point of insertion for the shader modifier but not an issue).

### I have tried

The following code in the surface modifier (`self.cellShadingModifier`).

```
vec4 geometry = u_inverseViewTransform * vec4(_surface.position, 1.0);
if (geometry.y < 0.0) {
_surface.diffuse.rgb *= vec3(0.4);
}
```

`_surface.position` is in view space, and I hoped to transform it to world space by using `u_inverseViewTransform`. [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNShadable_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Shader_Modifier_Entry_Point_Keys) says:

> Geometric fields (such as position and normal) are expressed in view
>   space. You can use SceneKit’s uniforms (such as
>   u_inverseViewTransform) to operate in a different coordinate space,
>   [...]

[image: The 3D plane with the geometry modifier and the surface modifier]

As you can see it is flickering and does not appear to be based on the the geometry.position I just modified. I have tested this both in the simulator and on device (iPad Air). I believe I am making a simple error as I'm probably confusing `_surface` and `_geometry` properties.

Can anyone tell me where I can get the z-coordinate (world space) of the currently shaded point of the mesh, so I can use it in my rendering method?

#### Note

I have also tried to access `_geometry` inside the surface shader modifier, but I get the error `Use of undeclared identifier '_geometry'`, which is strange because [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNShadable_Protocol/index.html) says:

> You can use the structures defined by earlier entry points in later
>   entry points. For example, a snippet associated with the
>   SCNShaderModifierEntryPointFragment entry point can read from the
>   _surface structure defined by the SCNShaderModifierEntryPointSurface entry point.

#### Note 2

I could have the LightingModel shader calculate off of the generated sine wave (and avoid the search for the z-coordinate), but in the future I may be adding additional waves and using the z-coordinate would be more maintainable, not to mention elegant.

Comment: The docs are half right. You can use info from earlier entry points *in the same shader stage*. But the geometry entry point runs in the vertex stage and the surface entry point runs in the fragment stage. (Unless, IIRC, you turn off per pixel lighting.)

Answer (score 4):

I've also been learning how to use the shader modifiers. I have a solution to this which works for me, using both the inverse model transform and the inverse view transform.

The following code will paint the right-hand side of the model at the centre of the scene with a red tint. You should be able to check the other position element (y, I think) to get the result you want.

```
vec4 orig = _surface.diffuse;
vec4 transformed_position = u_inverseModelTransform * u_inverseViewTransform * vec4(_surface.position, 1.0);
if (transformed_position.z < 0.0) {
    _surface.diffuse = mix(vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0), orig, 0.5);
}
```